# IOS 8 with IBM Worklight

Tags: ios8, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM worklight 6.0 for building a hybrid application. My application is running perfectly on IOS 7. When I migrated the same code to Xcode 6 beta for IOS 8 build, only the splashscreen with loader came up and the app hangs. From the logs I saw that the application goes to skinLoader.html. None of the events are called. 
To my curiosity I created a dummy worklight iphone environment and ran it on IOS8 and again the app got stuck on the splash itself. 
I had a deviceready event on the html which was not called. So I am curious to know if there are other issues other than the userAgent issues with the worklight for IOS8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Worklight 6.1 and iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777073/worklight-6-1-and-ios-8)

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug in iOS 8 beta 1 in Cordova applications and it is expected to be fixed in upcoming releases.

```
Applications that use Apache Cordova/PhoneGap are broken due to a bug that causes the window.navigator.userAgent object to become undefined when window.navigator is replaced by a pure JavaScript wrapper object.
```

[via](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/index.html)

and it is already answered in [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklightsmobileplayground/entry/ibm_worklight_and_ios_8?lang=en) forum.

Answer (score 0):

A fix for the stuck-at-splash is provided in an iFix release from September 18th via IBM Fix Central.

For more information please see this question: [Worklight 6.1 and iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777073/worklight-6-1-and-ios-8)

Scenarios:

- If a user has already upgraded to iOS8 and the application got stuck on the splash screen, AFAIK the way to handle it is to either:

  - Uninstall/re-install the application from the App Store.
  - Install a newer app version (see below) from the App Store.
- If a user did not yet upgrade to iOS8, it is best to use the fixed Worklight Studio to generate an updated app, increment its version and re-publish it. Then, Remote Disable the existing version and direct users to install the fixed version from the App Store; the fixed version should then continue to work after upgrading to iOS8.