# Worklight 6.1 and iOS 8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ios8

I have some Apps developed with WL 6.1 and now, I updated my device to iOS 8 and none of the App is working. All of then are stucked in the Splash Screen.

I can't update WL because my server is in the "old" version.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update:*
Please see the following tech note for iOS 8 support: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684538

The link includes download links for patched versions of Worklight 5.0.6, 6.0, 6.1 and 6.2 as well as a list of fixed issues and other instructions.

- The relevant iFix is that from *September 18th* at the least.
- The fix is Studio-only.
- Users of Worklight 6.1.0.x should use the iFix from *September 19th* containing an App Store submission bug fix.
- Users of Worklight 6.0.0.x should also delete the wlBuildResources folder from the tmp directory prior to generating the fixed version (close Eclipse > Delete > Open Eclipse).
- Due to the nature of the defect (in native code, before the Worklight framework initializes), there are no alternatives other than the below...

Scenarios:

- If a user has already upgraded to iOS8 and the application got stuck on the splash screen, AFAIK the way to handle it is to either:

  - Uninstall/re-install the application from the App Store.
  - Install a newer app version (see below) from the App Store.
- If a user did not yet upgrade to iOS8, it is best to use the fixed Worklight Studio to generate an updated app, increment its version and re-publish it. Then, Remote Disable the existing version and direct users to install the fixed version from the App Store; the fixed version should then continue to work after upgrading to iOS8.

---

*Old:*
Worklight in general does support iOS 8, but this is a specific scenario that requires further investigation. Thanks for the report, We're going to look into it.

Comment: Hi Idan, I did exactly what you suggested and the App is working.

Comment: My concern is with App that has content to be used offline or saved data that will be lost, using JSONStore, like mine.

Comment: Thanks. Re-installing is not a "real" solution for production-time. Need to understand what is your app doing. Can you send it?

Comment: @IdanAdar, our production app does not work after upgrading to iOS8 and it required a re-install. Have you had any progress with this or should I raise a PMR?

Comment: This scenario was tested and found working, so if it doesn't work for your app, sure, open a PMR and provide all details about your app (what worklight features does it use internally, etc).

Comment: We have the same problem.  Any 6.1 apps that existed on device before upgrade fails with:: <Warning>: Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.  If you do a fresh install of the app or if the app had never been opened before the upgrade it seems to work fine.  I know IOS8 changed the app data directory structure, could the app be storing the old structure somewhere?

Comment: Applications where this is already happened to cannot be "fixed" - a re-installation is the only way. For users that are still on iOS7, it is best to block them using Remote Disable and direct them to download a new version of the app; an additional iFix will be published hopefully tomorrow to address this issue.

Comment: Use the iFix to build the new app version that you will publish on the App Store.

Comment: @IdanAdar So there is another fix in addition to those listed on the website above?

Comment: Thanks, Idar do you know if it is the wlAppSupportDirLoc key in the plist that is causing the problem? i noticed it has the old pre ios8 path to Application Support directory.. just curious

Comment: Not sure I can disclose any specifics; it's a combination of Encrypt web resources, Direct Update, location of resources after upgrade/backup/restore...

Comment: Hey @IdanAdar, it looks like the interim fix actually upgrades the version to iOS8 rather than making apps built using Xcode5 be compatible on iOS8? We're not yet ready to upgrade to Xcode6 and want to keep building with XCode5(iOS7). 
The iFix I downloaded for 6.1.0.1 was called 6.1.0.2 but then in Eclipse it actually says 6.2.0.0 and the Console and everything has changed. It also required me to build using Xcode6.

Comment: 1) 6.1.0.2 was recently released, replacing 6.1.0.1, so that's why you see that. However, the version number is still at 6.1.0.1 for some reason - I see in both Worklight Studio and Console 6.1.0.01-20140918-1928; if you did not re-deploy the .war file in your production server, then you'll see the previous version for the console, as it originates from the .war; as for the xcode bit, I have no answer to that, you should still be able to use both Xcode 5 and 6. I also don't understand what do you mean in "... actually upgrades the version to iOS8"; Worklight can't upgrade your device.

Comment: Hi Idan, may I check with you when will this fix be available for Worklight 506x? Thanks!

Comment: It is available for all versions, per the tech note.

Comment: I mean the issue for: Applications where this is already happened to cannot be "fixed" - a re-installation is the only way. For users that are still on iOS7, it is best to block them using Remote Disable and direct them to download a new version of the app; an additional iFix will be published hopefully tomorrow to address this issue. 
As from the Fix Central, the latest version is Worklight v5.0.6.2 InterimFix 201409171225.

Comment: The 5.0.6.x iFix is being built now. Probably uploaded to Fix Central within the next 2-3 hours or so.

Comment: The fix for 5.0.6.x is now published.

Comment: I downloaded Worklight 6.0.0.2 from http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/ , it's release date is 15th September, Is that version ok?

Comment: No. You need the 18th Or newer per my instructions in the answer.

Comment: ok, thanks, and no need to install on the server side, for this 6.0.0.2 fix?

Comment: Studio only in order to generate the fixed project.

Comment: Idan, may I ask when the app got stuck at the splash screen, can it be connected to Worklight server so that I can pop-up an alert box to notify customer to re-install the app from App Store?

Comment: As I wrote - no. It is stuck in the native code, long before any sort of init takes place.

Comment: @IdanAdar I downloaded the 6.1.0.2-WL-StudioP2-IF201409222007.zip and patched into my Worklight Studo, now my project is migrated from 6.1.0.01 to 6.2.0, is this upgrade a must to the fixes?

Comment: Weird that you write it upgraded the project to 6.2 when you say you upgraded to 6.1.0.2...

Comment: @IdanAdar I was wondering the same. Just tested in new machine, Install New Software > Add > Archive. It shows the correct version (6.1.0.2) in t&c page, but it went straight to download 6.2 during the installation and only 6.2 was installed. Is the steps incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: Try to uncheck the check box for "check for updates" during installation.